# How to remove Submission information from webfrom module

Tags: 7

I am using webform module and when I get an email from a user it is displayed with this information:

Submitted on

Submitted by user:

Submitted values are:

I don't want to this information I just want to display form information only  .

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps to modify the email content, which comes to you on webform submission :

- Login to the system by Admin credentials.
- Go to webform page.
- Click the **Webform** tab.
- Click the **E-Mails** tab inside **Webform** tab.
- Click **Edit** in Operation column infront of email address set by you for mail.
- Find **E-mail template** & edit the content which goes to the email address set by you.

Check it as you are done.